# Как скачивать торренты с помощью python

Tags: python, torrent

Единственную библиотеку которую нашел это libtorrent, но документации не нашел

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Есть документация для C++, можно попытаться адаптировать её под Python

Comment: Можете пожалуйста скинуть ссылку на эту документацию

Comment: https://www.libtorrent.org/reference.html

Comment: И там же внизу есть ссылочка [python bindings](https://www.libtorrent.org/python_binding.html), в которой есть пример рабочего Python-кода с libtorrent (но полноценной документации для Python всё равно нету, придётся импровизировать)